# Jmeter retry services on failure

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded some services in jmeter. When I run the jmeter, one of the services sometimes receives the parameters from another service(through Json Path Postprocessor) and sometimes it does not. When it does not receive the parameters, it fails. I want my jmeter to retry all the services if a service fails, beginning from start.(Through my research I found that Jmeter retry has been stopped since Jmeter 2.1 and I am using jmeter 3.1).How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your "services" (whatever it is) in an endless loop via [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) and exit the loop if all the requests are successful.

Answer (score 0):

There's plugin [Retry Post-Processor](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-retrier) you can add in your request(s) scope

> JMeter plugin provides a Post-Processor that retries failed samples.

> Minimum JMeter version 5.0

[image]